# SystemUtil.Run will not execute file

Tags: hp-uft, uft14

I am new to UFT.  I am using *version 14.02 build 3792*.

I want to open an executable file but my app won't open.  The line of code passes the maintenance run and run, however, that's all; my window to launch the file won't open.

I have been looking for answers on *Google* all morning.
I have tried using *CMD* in my recording, only to find that doesn't work either.

My code is

```
SystemUtil.Run "C:\SIMULATOR\AGS Gate Simulator\version 2.7.8.5\AGSGateSimulator.exe","open"
```

I get nothing, except a passed test.

Comment: did you tried removing the 2 second parameter? So: `SystemUtil.Run "C:\SIMULATOR\AGS Gate Simulator\version 2.7.8.5\AGSGateSimulator.exe"`.

Comment: @Jonas Good morning, yes, I tried.  Same results. :(

Comment: Hi, did you trief starting the application manually? `Win + R` and type `C:\SIMULATOR\AGS Gate Simulator\version 2.7.8.5\AGSGateSimulator.exe`?

Comment: Good morning, yes. :(

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if there are special configurations needed to use with our internal software...  I am not the only one having problems with using UFT on the job.

Comment: Hi, can you try something easy: `SystemUtil.Run "C:/Windows/System32\cmd.exe"`? Will this start an console?

Comment: Yes, that command successfully opened a cmd console :)

Comment: so there need to be an problem executing your file. Can you try the following:
`Dim shell`
`Set shell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")`
`shell.run "C:\SIMULATOR\AGS Gate Simulator\version 2.7.8.5\AGSGateSimulator.exe"`

Comment: Good morning, @Jonas.  I was overseas and am just getting back.  I will try your suggestion asap. Thanks!